# Catch a specific exception using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to catch a specific exception using PowerShell. Please see below example:

```
try {
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]
}
catch [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] {
    "File not found"
}
catch {
    "Exception type: $($_.Exception.GetType().Name)"
}
```

Output from this code is: `Exception type: RuntimeException`

The output I am expecting is: "File not found"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `throw <typeName>`. You need to throw an *instance* of an exception type.

Change the `throw` statement to:

```
throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]::new("Failed to find that file you asking for", "<attempted file name/path goes here>")
```